# How to preview image in image view after picture taken from camera

Tags: android

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9e8439/how-to-make-a-custom-camera-ion-android/I have made a custom camera app and after click a picture i want to preview it in an image view but when i am previewing it in image view,image is being scaled from actual size of picture.

Comment: add your code so that we can modify

Comment: i have provided link where i created my custom camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

his is how I made it work for me! Assuming you are capturing an image, and would like to show the captured image in a new Activity, you can follow this way:

First on the click of button you can:

```
    public void cameraFuture(View view) // <-- onClick() method of Camera Button
{
    Intent intent= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "MyPhoto.jpg");
    outPutfileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outPutfileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PIC);
}
```

Then on the `onActivityResult()` method, you can do this way:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PIC && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        Toast.makeText(this, outPutfileUri.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent bitIntent = new Intent(this, CameraTake.class);
        bitIntent.putExtra("imageUri", outPutfileUri);
        startActivity(bitIntent);
        finish();


    }

}
```

And in the next Activity, you can receive the file this way:

```
Intent receiveIntent = getIntent();

uri = receiveIntent.getParcelableExtra("imageUri");


if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras == null) {
        receiveImg= null;
    } else {
        receiveImg= extras.getString("PASSER");
    }
} else {
    receiveImg= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("PASSER");
}




File imgFile = new  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyPhoto.jpg");

if(imgFile.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camOut);

    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Has he posted his code? , its a common issue, when snapped pic using camera gets a poor quality, I posted a solution in that aspect, this returns the image with original quality!  And I've tested it personally

Answer (score -1):

[This link](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) completely described what you want. Here is the summary:

1- Add this to the Manifest:

```
< uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

2- Add this line to your class:

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
```

3- call this method where you want to open camera:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

4- Override onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        ImageView ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        ivImage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

I hope it help you.